# Update file located at VSTS repository from javascript Appication

Tags: javascript, azure-devops

I have developed VSTS extension using javascript where i read files(CSV file) from VSTS repository using "vss-web-extension-sdk" npm package.

Below method gives file content

```
 async getItemContent(filepath,dataRepository,dataProject) {
        let raw = await this.gitRestClient.getItemContent(dataRepository, filepath, dataProject);
        return this.decoder.decode(raw);
    }
```

This is my demo repository.

[image]

Here input parameters would be

filepath - "data/a.csv"

dataRepository - "TestRepo"

dataProject - "BuildDemoProject"

Reading the csv file is working fine. Now i want to update the file and send back to the repository.

**Update 1:**

I found a way to push the changes using GitHttpClient Api as below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/reference/client/api/tfs/versioncontrol/gitrestclient/githttpclient2_2?view=vsts#createpush()

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#update_a_file

Request parameters are

```
{
  "refUpdates": [
    {
      "name": "refs/heads/master",
      "oldObjectId": "fd1062428e0567cfbfcc28ac59d4bea077ce81c1"
    }
  ],
  "commits": [
    {
      "comment": "Added a few more items to the task list.",
      "changes": [
        {
          "changeType": "edit",
          "item": {
            "path": "/tasks.md"
          },
          "newContent": {
            "content": "# Tasks\n\n* Item 1\n* Item 2\n* Item 3\n* Item 4\n\nIf you need to add more, update this file and add them!",
            "contentType": "rawtext"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now my query is what should be the value of "oldObjectId" in request parameter.

Comment: could you figure this out? I am trying something similar where i want to read files from VSTS repo.

Comment: I am using vss-web-extension-sdk and I am able to read file from VSTS

Comment: are you authenticating the user with active directory? if yes, can you please tell how?